# Default value in Knex migration for an specific type of text array not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am creating a database migration using Knex (v0.19.5) and PostgreSQL (v10.1) but when I try to set the default value to a `TEXT` array column it gives me a `malformed array literal` error.

```
table.specificType('test', 'TEXT[]').defaultTo(['foo', 'bar']);
```

This is the error message

> Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
>
> error: malformed array literal: "foo,bar"

Maybe I am missing something but I can't get it to work and I can't find anything useful in their [official docs](http://knexjs.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved it by simply setting the array into a literal string.

```
table.specificType('test', 'TEXT[]').defaultTo('{\'\'foo\'\',\'\'bar\'\'}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `pg.raw('...')`

```js
table.specificType("test", "text[]").defaultTo(pg.raw(`'{}'::text[]`))
```